# <THEAD> is not being honored when using Print Preview with a CHtmlView control

Tags: html-table, mfc, webbrowser-control

I have a basic HTML `table` object which has a `thead` section:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td class="columnStudyPoint">Study Point</td>
        <td class="columnDate">Date Assigned</td>
        <td class="columnDate">Date Completed</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Now, if I open my HTML document in Microsoft Edge and do a Print Preview I see that it is working:

[image: Preview]

However, I am displaying this HTML document inside a `CHtmlView` web browser control which uses IE7 under the hood. In this context, the `thead` is not repeated when doing a Print Preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I add this to my CSS document:

```
@media print {
   thead {
       display: table-header-group;
   }

   table tbody tr td:before,
   table tbody tr td:after {
        content : "" ;
        height : 4px ;
        display : block ;
    }
}
```

Preview of page 2 in the `CHtmlView` control:

[image: Preview in CHtmlView]