# CHtmlEditCtrl::PrintDocument() - lines near the page bottom have wrong spacing?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to print document using the method of `CHtmlEditCtrl::PrintDocument()` as described here ([Printing In MFC Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982965/printing-in-mfc-application)). Below is my test code where I plan to print a pretty big table.

```
void CMyView::OnFilePrint()
{
    CHtmlEditCtrl PrintCtrl;
    if (!PrintCtrl.Create(NULL, WS_CHILD, CRect(0, 0, 0, 0), this, 1))
    {
        ASSERT(FALSE);
        return;
    }

    CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> document;
    PrintCtrl.GetDocument(&document);
    WaitForComplete(document);
    CString html = 
        _T("<!doctype html>")
        _T("<html lang=\"en\">")
        _T("  <head>")
        _T("    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">")
        _T("    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\">")
        _T("    <title>HTML5 Test Page</title>")
        _T("    <style>")
        _T("      @media print")
        _T("      {")
        _T("        td { overflow-x:auto }")
        _T("      }")
        _T("    </style>")
        _T("    <style type=\"text/css\">")
        _T("      thead { display:table-header-group }")
        _T("      tfoot { display:table-footer-group; page-break-inside:avoid }")
        _T("      tbody { display:table-row-group }")
        _T("      td > div { display:block; page-break-inside:avoid }")
        _T("    </style>")
        _T("  </head>")
        _T("  <body>")
        _T("    <div id=\"top\" class=\"page\" role=\"document\">")
        _T("      <header role=\"banner\">")
        _T("        <p>This is header.</p>")
        _T("      </header>")
        _T("      <main role=\"main\">")
        _T("        <section id=\"text\">")
        _T("          <article id=\"text_tables\">")
        _T("            <table>")
        _T("            <thead>")
        _T("                <tr>")
        _T("                    <th>")
        _T("                        header comes here for each page")
        _T("                    </th>")
        _T("                </tr>")
        _T("            </thead>")
        _T("            <tfoot>")
        _T("                <tr>")
        _T("                    <td>")
        _T("                        footer comes here for each page")
        _T("                    </td>")
        _T("                </tr>")
        _T("            </tfoot>");
        _T("            <tbody>");
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
    {
        CString str;
        str.Format(_T("%d"), i);
        html = html + "<tr><td><div>" + str + "</div></td></tr>";
    }
    html = html + "</tbody></table></article></section></main>";
    html = html + "<footer role=\"contentinfo\"><p>This is footer</p></footer></div></body></html>";
    PrintCtrl.SetDocumentHTML(html);
    WaitForComplete(document);
    //PrintCtrl.PrintPreview();
    PrintCtrl.PrintDocument();
}
```

The problem is for every line near the page bottom, there seems to be a mess of spacing. See attached picture below, note that 41 has more spacing from 40 and gets partially cut off. How does it happen and how to fix it?

[image]

I try adding repeated header and footer, below is part of the result that displaying error.

[image]

I try using "td {overflow-x:auto;}". The table footer of the first page is not shown correctly.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing HTML tables without splitting a row across two pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586250/printing-html-tables-without-splitting-a-row-across-two-pages)

Comment: I think you just have to use CSS styling to make the row not split over a page. Several of the answers to the duplicate question indicate this.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, Thanks. I've tried it (see my new edit), not working. One thing is that I have to use VS8 (quite old I admit) whose web controller may not recognize page-break options, I guess? Is there other way of fixing the issue?

Comment: Besides, there is another issue why the bottom line has more spacing? If that can be fixed, it may solve the line splitting.

Comment: I have another case where there are more than one column. The split happens so that the first column is on the first page and the rest columns are on the second page, so weird.

Comment: I think what I did in the end is use a thead section at the top with a row of column headings. These get repeated when you print at top of each page.

Comment: The spacing is managed by your Internet Explorer Page Setup. Change margins in there will change them in your browser control.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, Thanks. If you can, please check my recent edit. I add repeated header and footer and the error still exists. Note that, it seems to happen randomly (e.g., not from page 1 to page 2, but from page 2 to page 3).

Comment: No matter what margin is set, it should apply consistently, right? Here, only "77" has more spacing from "78", why?

Comment: That looks like a bug with browser control. The html content can be saved to file, and open/print with Internet Explorer, it look okays without that bug. But direct print preview shows the bug.

Comment: The control is bugged. It doesn’t work right with scaled text systems with ultra hd monitors. I raised it with ms and they have not resolved it. I had to add a Preview in External browser option to my editor with a list of browsers so those with issues could still print.

Comment: I end up inserting page break periodically to avoid the issue. Thank you guys for the help!

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Do you have a link to your question posted on Microsoft, or do you have a stackoverlow question posted here. Do you know if that issue occurs with Internet Explorer or is it just with html control?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I had several issues. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49264984/thead-is-not-being-honored-when-using-print-preview-with-a-chtmlview-control   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43101923/repeating-row-headings-in-print-preview-for-table-thead-doesnt-work-correctly   This last one is for the bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52137889/chtmlview-that-is-compatible-with-ultrahd It links to MS issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/215368/chtmlview-and-printing-on-ultrahd-computers.html

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug with `IWebBrowser2` interface. It can be fixed with `td{overflow-x: auto;}`

```html
<style>
@media print
{ 
    td{overflow-x: auto;} 
}
</style>
```

Comment: I try your approach. It works except only for the first page where table footer is cut across. Please check my new edit and see if it can be fixed. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You have changed the question, `<tbody>` is not added, there seems to be other html errors.